# Generating function of the succession $\{\frac{n^{3}}{n!}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, formal-power-series

I'm having serious trouble with this question. What is the generating function of $\{\frac{n^{3}}{n!}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$?
I have thought first that I know some things related to this.
Firstly, I know that the generating function of $\{\frac{1}{n!}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is $e^{x}$, just using Taylor. Secondly, I also know that the generating function of $\{n^{3}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is $\left(x\frac{\delta}{\delta x}\right)^{3}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=\frac{x^3+4x^2+x}{(1-x)^{4}}$. Nevertheless, multiplying this two generating functions doesn't give me the one that I am looking for...
After this point, I have ran out of valid ideas... a little hint would be extremely appreciated! Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Do you know the logic behind the expression $\left(x\frac{\delta}{\delta x}\right)^{3}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)$? Can you apply the logic here?

Comment: hint: $\left(x\frac{\delta}{\delta x}\right)$ can be viewed as an operator on the space of functions. What will you get if you apply it 3 times to $e^x$?

Comment: The suggestion by Misha Lavrov and Achille Hui is undoubtedly the simplest way. Alternatively you can try and write $n^3$ as a linear combination of $n(n-1)(n-2)$,
$n(n-1)$, $n$ and $1$ (constant coefficients), and then cancel those factors from the factorial.

Comment: Thanks all for answering! I understand your proposals! Yes, I know the logic behind that expression, and applying to this particular case, I obtained that the the generating function is $(x^3+3x^2+x)\cdot e^{x}$ which I have confirmed to be okay with a calculating program! I will also take a try on your proposal, Jyrki, thanks a lot!